# How to list datasets for two selected dates?

Tags: r

I have thousands of different files (having the same names and extension `.img`) in a folder called `data`. what change is only the date. If I use this :

```
 dir<- list.files ("C:\\Users\\data", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
```

It will list all files I have in the folder `data`.

What I need is just to list the files dated from `01062005 to 29102008`:

Examples how the files are named:

```
 File_yyyymmdd_data.img     (in which yyyymmdd varies for 10 years)
```

Any idea or hint is appreciated!

Comment: I think you need `paste` and `seq`.  First convert the `01062005` to `20102008` to 'Date` with `as.Date`. use `seq` to the sequence of dates, format with `format` to convert back to the original format and `paste` with `data.img` and read with `read.table/read.csv` in a list using `lapply`

Comment: @sacvf why not read the full set of files, extract the desired part of the name to a separate vector as a date and the subset values using the *dated* column?

Comment: @sacvf That is what I meant by `read.table/read.csv` (to read all the files with the selected date names)

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have files with "dated names", formatted as in your post: "File_yyyymmdd_data.img"

```
list.files.by.datedNames <- function(
  from,     # time starts
  to,       # time ends
  tz="GMT", # time zone
  myfiles   # a vector of all files
  ){
  mydates <- gsub("File_([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})_data.img","\\1-\\2-\\3",myfiles)

  .from <- as.POSIXct(from,tz=tz)
  .to <- as.POSIXct(to,tz=tz)
  .whether <- vapply(mydates,function(e){
    .e <- as.POSIXct(e,tz=tz);    
    as.numeric(.e)>=as.numeric(.from) & as.numeric(.e)<=as.numeric(.to)
  },logical(1),USE.NAMES=FALSE)

  ret <- myfiles[.whether]
  return(ret)    
}

## Call it in your case
list.files.by.datedNames(
  "2005-06-01","2008-10-29",
  myfiles=list.files("C:\\Users\\data", "*.img"))

## ## A tested example to touch and check files in current working directory
## > system("touch File_20050101_data.img")
## > system("touch File_20060101_data.img")
## > system("touch File_20080101_data.img")
## > system("touch File_20090101_data.img")
## >
## > list.files.by.datedNames(
## +   "2005-06-01","2008-10-29",
## +   myfiles=list.files(pattern="*.img"))
## [1] "File_20060101_data.img" "File_20080101_data.img"
```

2) Or you select files by modification/creation/access time:

```
list.files2 <- function(
  from,     # time starts
  to,       # time ends
  tz="GMT", # time zone
  which.time=c("mtime","ctime","atime"), # modification/creation/access time?
  ...       # additional arguments passed to `list.files` function
  ){
  which.time <- match.arg(which.time)


  .files <- list.files(...)
  .from <- as.POSIXct(from,tz=tz)
  .to <- as.POSIXct(to,tz=tz)

  .whether <- vapply(.files,function(e){
    tmp=file.info(e)[[which.time]];
    as.numeric(tmp)>=as.numeric(.from) & as.numeric(tmp)<=as.numeric(.to)
  },logical(1),USE.NAMES=FALSE)

  ret <- .files[.whether]
  return(ret)  
}

## Call it in your case
list.files2("2005-06-01","2008-10-29",path="C:\\Users\\data",pattern="*.img")

## ## Continue with the above example [in 1)] to check files that were modified today; 
## ## set `tz` according to your time zone.
## > list.files2("2015-04-23","2015-04-24",tz="EDT",pattern="*.img")
## [1] "File_20050101_data.img" "File_20060101_data.img" "File_20080101_data.img"
## [4] "File_20090101_data.img"
```

Comment: @sacvf It converts "yyyymmdd" to "yyyy-mm-dd" by group capture via regular expression. [Read more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

Comment: @sacvf In the 1st solution, be sure the "yyyymmdd" part in your file names be a valid date. e.g. "20050532" would raise such an error condition. You may print intermediate results to figure out what is exactly wrong.

Comment: @sacvf I made a typo it should be `as.POSIXct` in `.to <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(to),tz=tz)` instead of `as.POSIXlt`

Comment: @sacvf (Tested) examples added for your reference. FYI, the functions were also slightly simplified.

Comment: @sacvf In 1) you can feed `myfiles` with a vector of full file paths by calling `list.files` with the option `full.names=TRUE`. In 2), you can similarly pass the option `full.names=TRUE` to `list.files2`, which then passed to the inner function `list.files`.

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in the comments, I would like to suggest reading the full file list and subsequently creating a normal column with date via the usual set of string manipulations and subsetting the new vector with use of the desired date range. For example,

```
rm(list = ls())
mydates <- as.Date(c("2007-06-22", "2004-02-13", "2004-02-14","2004-02-15"))
subs.dates <- mydates[mydates <= "2004-02-14"]
```

the subset would contain:

```
> subs.dates
[1] "2004-02-13" "2004-02-14"
```